# Imagen de fondo que ocupe toda la pagina web con angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap

Quisiera agregar una imagen de fondo que ocupe todo el largo y ancho de mi pagina web

```css
/* aqui le añado estilos al div con la imagen de fondo para que esta se alargue y tome la imagen de fondo hasta el final de la pagina */

.container-fluid{
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!-- aqui cargo la imagen de fondo -->
<div class="container-fluid position-absolute" style="background:url(https://aldanalaser.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/fondo-3.jpg?w=842);">
  <div class="container ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta "estirar" la imagen para que no se repita y hacer que el fondo use toda la pantalla (el 100% del viewport).

```css
/* aqui le añado estilos al div con la imagen de fondo para que esta se alargue y tome la imagen de fondo hasta el final de la pagina */

.container-fluid{
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    background-image:url("https://aldanalaser.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/fondo-3.jpg?w=842");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!-- aqui cargo la imagen de fondo -->
<div class="container-fluid position-absolute">
  <div class="container ">
```